# How to pass string with serialized JSON instead of JSON object in curl parameters

Tags: php, json, string

I am using vdociepher, So I need to pass few parameters to vdociepher url but it is recommended to pass " string with serialized JSON instead of JSON object " So I am passing this as per requirement ,but php showing code error like wrong format or improper way of writing.

```
CURLOPT_URL => "https://dev.vdocipher.com/api/videos/1234567890/otp",
  
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
    'licenseRules': json_encode({
      'canPersist' => true,
      'rentalDuration' => 15 * 24 * 3600
    })
  ]),
```

I above url I am getting php error in below lines:

```
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
        'licenseRules': json_encode({
          'canPersist' => true,
          'rentalDuration' => 15 * 24 * 3600
        })
      ]),
```

So what is proper way to write string with serialized json

Comment: @Syscall  as per official document of vdociepher we need to write like that

Comment: @Syscall https://dev.vdocipher.com/api/docs/book/playbackauth/offline.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typo errors. `json_encode({` should be `json_encode([`, `})` should be `])`, and `'licenseRules':` should be `'licenseRules' =>`.

```
json_encode([
    'licenseRules' => json_encode([
      'canPersist' => true,
      'rentalDuration' => 15 * 24 * 3600
    ])
]),
```

But you will have "double encoded" JSON.
I think that you should send data like this :

```
json_encode([
    'licenseRules' => [
          'canPersist' => true,
          'rentalDuration' => 15 * 24 * 3600,
    ]
]),
```

Comment: https://dev.vdocipher.com/api/docs/book/playbackauth/offline.html# please follow  mentioned url

Comment: OK. I see. The first part of the answer should help (https://3v4l.org/7Hp9S).